# Checking column stats in Oracle 12

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

In Oracle I can do:

```
SELECT *  
 FROM ALL_TAB_STATS_HISTORY;
```

and figure out last time stats was run for various tables. 
Similarly, I can get the stats information columns by doing:

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_COL_STATISTICS WHERE OWNER = 'CURAM' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
```

What about for index tables?  Does Oracle also store stats for index tables? And how do I check the last time they were run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ALL_TAB_COLUMNS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.html#GUID-F218205C-7D76-4A83-8691-BFD2AD372B63)

> **LAST_ANALYZED**
>
> Date on which this column was most recently analyzed

[ALL_INDEXES](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/ALL_INDEXES.html#GUID-E39825BA-70AC-45D8-AF30-C7FF561373B6)

> **LAST_ANALYZED**
>
> Date on which this index was most recently analyzed

Comment: Any reason why you would do ALL_TAB_COLUMNS instead of ALL_TAB_COL_STATISTICS?  Thanks

Comment: @MoreThanFive For this purpose, it does not matter. `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` returns more information about columns, and `ALL_TAB_COLS` returns even more.